# Passing React state variable to static page to render

Tags: reactjs, react-props

Passing state to a static component, and using the variable for display.
New to React, on an inherited codebase.

in `Routes.js` we have

```
componentDidMount() {
...catching an error ...
this.setState({ serverError: true, errorStack: err.response.data.stack, errorMsg: err.response.data.message });    
}
```

later we have:

```
render() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <ScrollToTop>
            <Switch>
              {
                  this.state.serverError ?
                    <Route component={Page500} />
```

and then we have Page500.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "reactstrap";

const Page500 = (props) => (
  <div className="text-center">
    <h1 className="display-1 font-weight-bold">500</h1>
    <p className="h1">Internal server error.</p>
    <p className="h2 font-weight-normal mt-3 mb-4">
      The server encountered something unexpected that didn&apos;t allow it to
      complete the request. <br />
      Error: {props.errorMsg}
    </p>
    <a href=".">
      <Button color="primary" size="lg">
        Return to website
      </Button>
    </a>
  </div>
);

export default Page500;
```

I am trying to print `errorMsg` in the Page500 function, but for some reason nothing works, even "this" is undefined and not sure how to read state from Routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the error message in Router through the props

```
<Route render={(props) => <Page500 {...props} errorMsg={this.state.errorMsg} />} />
```

Comment: is there a way to pass the entire `state` and not individual errorMsg?

Comment: pass `state={this.state}`, you can get your entire state in props.state